# incorrect Response after second request using rest kit

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

i m new with restkit and i have an issue with that. I have a restservice for check in. So i m calling my restservice with a "Put"-request. Looks like that Put: http: ... /api/v1/locations/location/[Location-ID]/checkin?userId=[User-ID]. The response is a , so i called it checkin-object. After the check in i m calling another service (Get-Request). But the new mapping-result of the get-request includes previous checkin-object. How do i reset/erase it?

```
[self.restHelper checkinUser:[NSNumber numberWithInt:USER_ID] forLocationID:self.selectedLocation success:successBlock failure:failureBlock];
```

the mapping:

```
- (void)checkinUser:(NSNumber*) userID forLocationID:(NSNumber *)locationID success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *, RKMappingResult *))success failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *, NSError *))failure{

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

RKObjectMapping *userCheckinMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CheckIN class]];
[userCheckinMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"locationFullname" : @"locationFullname",
 @"userNameCityCountry" : @"userNameCityCountry",
 @"success" : @"success",
 }];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userCheckinMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".../api/v1/locations/location/%@/checkin?userId=%@", locationID,userID];

[objectManager putObject:nil path:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    success(operation, mappingResult);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    failure(operation,error);
}];
```

}

The next call is like that:

```
 -(void)getTracksForLocation:(NSNumber *)locationID withType:(NSString*) type success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *, RKMappingResult *))success failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *, NSError *))failure{

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

RKObjectMapping *trackResultsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RESTTracksResult class]];
[trackResultsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id" : @"ID",
 @"cued" : @"cued",
 @"marked" : @"marked",
 @"playing": @"playing",
 @"played": @"played",
 @"creditBidSum": @"creditBidSum",
 }];

RKObjectMapping *trackMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RESTTrack class]];
[trackMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 //@"id" : @"ID",
 @"name" : @"name",
 @"artistName" : @"artistName",
 @"genre": @"genre",
 @"length": @"length",
 }];

RKRelationshipMapping* relationShipMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"track"
                                                                                         toKeyPath:@"track"
                                                                                       withMapping:trackMapping];

[trackResultsMapping addPropertyMapping:relationShipMapping];


RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:trackResultsMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"results" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

NSDictionary *trackDictionary = @{ @"type": type};

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".../api/v1/locations/location/%@/tracks", locationID ];

[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:trackDictionary success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    success(operation, mappingResult);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    failure(operation,error);
}];
```

}

Hopefully you can help me, ty! I have also tried do delete the cache but it didn`t work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a few things wrong, and they mean that when you make the second call, all of the configuration from the first call is being used to try to understand the second response.

1.

When you're using an object manager, you should be setting the base URL. You might already be doing this, it's hard to tell. Then, whenever you specify a path it should be relative to that base.

2.

When you create the path, don't add the parameters. That's what the `parameters` parameter is for on the put and get methods.

3.

If you're using the `sharedManager`, you should do all of your mapping configuration once. Don't add additional mappings each time you call your methods.

4.

When you create response descriptors, set the path pattern and key path. This is your main problem. If you don't set them, RestKit will always try to use rack mapping to process each response. This will result in you getting unexpected objects, probably win partial information, in your mapping result.

Comment: ty, that helped me a lot. During programming i forgot to set the path patterns.